# How to transfer ubuntu 20.10 from HDD to SSD, i already have windows 10 installed on SSD

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, hard-disk, ssd

I have a 128 GB SSD in which Windows 10 is installed and Ubuntu is installed in a HDD.
I want to install Ubuntu on the SSD without making any changes to Windows 10.
Is there any way I can transfer Ubuntu to the SSD without reinstalling it?

Comment: Better to just do a new install to a new / partition on SSD. I just did this as I only have Ubuntu on SSD and had some space. It was suggested to try Kubuntu, so I installed it to my HDD as a temporary install, but liked it so much, I then installed to SSD. Then cp -a copied (usually use rsync) my /home from HDD to SSD and the configuration changes were all there. You may want to export list of installed apps & use that to reinstall. I use a script for almost all the apps I want, but export list of installed apps as part of my normal backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make new partition on ssd for ubuntu.
2. use `dd` command to copy data to new partition.
   and then install grub and update it using live boot disk.

dd command example
`dd if=/dev/hdd1 of=/dev/nvmep1s2`

Comment: If UEFI with gpt partitioning, you cannot use dd on just a partition. The gpt partitioning has a unique GUID for every partition that also is stored in the primary partition table and the backup partition table. You can use dd if the old MBR partitioning is uses where Windows 10 is an upgrade from Windows 7 in BIOS boot mode. But really better to do new install.

Comment: @oldfred you are right. can you update the answer for UEFI?

Comment: @AkhilJalagam i have successfully copied ubuntu from HDD to SSD and installed grub. Now I see two ubuntu  opiton  and one windows option in my boot menu. The two ubuntu are from HDD and SSD but whenever i select ubuntu on /dev/sdb4 (SSD) my HDD ubuntu gets booted. How do i solve this problem?